# How can I calculate the angle of an ellipse given it's matrix representation?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have the following two matrices which represent two ellipses with different angles of rotation:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0.137956 & 0.00275827 \\ 0.00275827 & 0.0406408\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0.0698865 & 0.0545128 \\ 0.0545128 & 0.0698865\end{pmatrix}$$

From the matrices, how can I calculate the angle of rotation of each ellipse ?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: I have looked through many of the relevant posts before posting my question. My math level is maybe not sufficient for extracting a practical solution for me from these posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to compute eigenvectors of a matrix, then you can find the rotation angle by computing them for this matrix because the eigenvectors of the matrix of a conic point in the directions of its principal axes.

Alternatively, you can solve for it directly. When an ellipse is axis-aligned, its equation doesn’t have any $xy$ terms. This corresponds to the off-diagonal entries of the matrices being zero. So, you need to find the rotation angle that will make these entries vanish. Rotating an ellipse through an angle $-\theta$ is accomplished with the following matrix multiplication: $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.\tag{*}$$ Expanding the off-diagonal elements results in the equation $$b\cos2\theta+\frac12(a-c)\sin2\theta = 0$$ from which $$\tan2\theta = {2b\over c-a}.$$ If you’re coding this, I suggest using the two-parameter version of the arctangent function since the denominator could be zero. Note, too, that there’s more than one possible rotation angle, all 90° apart, so you’ll have to decide which of these you mean by *the* rotation angle. For instance, if you want the angle to the major axis, you’ll need to add the constraint that the upper-left element in the result of the product (*) is less than the lower-right one. In terms of eigenvectors, you want the eigenvector that corresponds to the *smaller* eigenvalue in absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for describing these two approaches so clearly and the word of caution about the arctangent function. I will try both. Much appreciated !